# Found Gradle version Gradle 7.4. Versions Gradle 6.0.0 and newer are not supported in FG3, FG4 however supports Versions 6.8.1 and newer

Tags: gradle, minecraft-forge

I have a problem with Gradle. I'm trying to make a mod for Minecraft 1.12.2 and I'm using Intellij IDEA. Everything works fine for the version 1.16.4, but if I want to build a mod for the 1.12 I get this error:

> Failed to apply plugin 'net.minecraftforge.gradle'.
> Found Gradle version Gradle 7.4. Versions Gradle 6.0.0 and newer are not supported in FG3, FG4 however supports Versions 6.8.1 and newer. Consider upgrading.

It's supposed to do something with `apply plugin: 'net.minecraftforge.gradle'` in the build.gradle file.

I don't have much experience with this sort of stuff so please help me. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

to write a mod for 1.12.2, Forge provides a [build.gradle file](https://adfoc.us/serve/sitelinks/?id=271228&url=https://maven.minecraftforge.net/net/minecraftforge/forge/1.12.2-14.23.5.2860/forge-1.12.2-14.23.5.2860-mdk.zip). In this, the 3.+ (FG3) is specified as the ForgeGradle version.

The current version of Gradle (7.4.2) only supports ForgeGradle versions from FG4 and newer.

- FG3 - older than Gradle version 6.0.0
- FG4 - Gradle version 6.8.1 and newer

You now have two options:

1. You take the Gradle version 7.4.2 and make a mod for a Minecraft version with a ForgeGradle version from FG4 or newer.
2. You take an older Gradle version.